# How can I print the content of a <span> in Cucumber / Capybara?

Tags: ruby, debugging, cucumber, capybara

I want to print the content of a error message that is situated in a span and looks something like this:

```
<span>Es exisitiert bereits ein Account mit dieser E-Mail Adresse. Wenn Sie sich sicher sind, dass dies Ihre Adresse ist, dann klicken Sie <a href="https://link-removed.com">hier</a> um das Passwort und den Zugang zu Ihrem Account zu erhalten.</span>
```

In my step definition, I tried the following

```
print page.find('.error-msg span')
```

This, however, doesn't really work. After googling for an hour I couldn't find anything that worked, which may also be due to the fact that I am pretty much new to all of this.

I basically want to debug, so I want to see what the actual content is. It will also be helpful for future endeavours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `text` against that.

```
puts page.find('.error-msg span').text
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element

Comment: I actually did use that, but got a strange output (mostly just strange letters that I couldn't make sense of). I found out that updating ruby might resolve that issue. I just did that and now `puts page.find('.error-msg span').text` works

Answer (score 0):

You should use rspec matchers to either pass or fail the bug. Doing this will print out a helpful message on the page.

```
Given I visit a page
Then I should see "foo" in ".error-msg span"

Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)" in "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, css|
  page.should have_selector(tag, text: text )
end
```

If you use this and there is a '.error-msg span' element on the page and if the text does not match what you expected, the error message that Capybara displays will tell you what was inside the selector. Example:

```
      expected to find css ".error-msg span" with text "foo" but there were no matches. Also found "Bar", which matched the selector but not all filte
```

rs. (Capybara::ExpectationNotMet)

Translation: The text inside '.error-msg span' was "bar" not "foo"

Answer (score 0):

you can use this either,because All you need is to verify the text in that span:

```
Then /^I should see (.+) as content in xpath "([^"]*)"$/ do |content, xpath|
  assert page.find(:xpath, xpath + "[contains(string(), '" + content +"')]")
end
```

Give the xpath of your span.It works with Strings Only

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach. Add a file elements.rb to your support folder and have this within it:

```
 def text(type=nil)
    type ||= :all unless Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements or Capybara.visible_text_only
   synchronize do
  if type == :all
     base.all_text
  else
      base.visible_text
  end
 end
end
```

Then write your step definition as follows (example):

```
within(:id, "") do 
    page.should have_content("")
         puts text
    end
end
```

You can just add `puts text` to the end of any step definition in future to output the element text